# Variable passing

Tags: function-construction, homework

I am having trouble understanding how variables are passed in as parameters.

My goal is to create a function

```
f(logical,x,y,z) = Evaluate [logical(x,y,z)]
```

From there I should be able to call `f(x||y||z, x,y,z)`

and it will output `(false||false||false)`.

My current format:

```
func1[expr_,xval_,yval_,zval] = expr /. {xval->x, yval ->y, zval ->z}
```

Obviously this is wrong because I have yet to define x,y,z until I call the function. Really just unsure of the format and have no idea where to go.

Comment: `func1` is just `ReplaceAll`, maybe with `Hold` or `Defer`. Try `ReplaceAll[Hold[x||y||z],{x->False, y->False, z->False}]` or  `ReplaceAll[Defer[x||y||z],{x->False, y->False, z->False}]`. If you want it in function form, just set `HoldFirst` or `HoldAll` to the function.

Comment: Why would `f[x || y || z, x, y, z]` necessarily return `False || False || False`? If `x`, `y` and `z` were `False`, it would automatically evaluate to just `False` (hence @b3m2a1's comment). If `x`, `y` and `z` did not have truth values it would just return unevaluated `x || y || z`.

Comment: Please find a descriptive title for your questions.  See the [asking guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend starting in the  [wolfram documentation for functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html). I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do with your inputs, but I believe you want to make a function that evaluates some other function or functions. You could write this as

```
func1[expr_, x_, y_, z_] := expr[x, y, z];
```

then create whatever expressions you need to evaluate

```
equation1[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;
equation2[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
```

then pass them both into `func1`

```
func1[#, 1, 2, 3] & /@ {equation1, equation2}
```

For a logical function it is similar. Lets assume you have defined variables somewhere in your book

```
x=1;
y=2;
z=3;
```

then

```
equation3[a_, b_, c_] := x == a || y == b || z == c;
```

will check if the inputs a, b, or c are equal to x, y, or z, respectively. So

```
func1[eq3, 1, 23, 45]
```

will give you True, since `a` (1) is equal to x. Finally, to output some array, just make the equation an array:

```
equation4[a_, b_, c_] := {TrueQ[x == a], TrueQ[y == b], TrueQ[z == c]}
```

then

```
func1[equation4, 1, 2, 3]
```

returns

```
{True, False, False}
```

Comment: `func1[Or, x, y, z]` (returns `x || y || z`) might clarify things for the OP. Also, `func1` is essentially `Apply`.